# Using JSP, display org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[] as String / XML output

Tags: java, jsp, axis

I'm trying to display the output as either String / XML format on JSP.

```
org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[] msgElement = getScheduleData.get_any();
```

Here data is stored on `msgElement` variable.

What are the steps i need to take to display the `msgElement` output as XML / String Format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add more details. what does it contains ?

Comment: @Joshi: The method `getScheduleData.get_any()` returns an XML form data. Is there any way to display whatever data is returning by the method that I should display?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your jsp file, where ever you want to display.

```
<% org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[] type_any138 = getScheduleData.get_any();
    String temp_any138 = null;
    if(type_any138 != null){
    java.util.List list_any138= java.util.Arrays.asList(type_any138);
    temp_any138 = list_any138.toString();
    }
%>        
<%=temp_any138%>
```